# Check for differences in permuted files

Tags: bash

I have the following folder structure

```
folderA 
   folderX
       fileX.txt
       fileY.txt
folderB 
   folderX
       fileX.txt
       fileY.txt
```

Where the content of fileX.txt (and fileY.txt) in folderA is a permutated version of the one in folderB (same lines, just in a different order)

Now, I want to check this using a bash command.
I know the command to compare to directories is
`diff -qr folderA/ folderB/` and the command to check if permutated files are the same is `diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)`

But how can I combine these to commands? Meaning, how can I check if within a folder structure, the files are the same except for a permutation.

Suppose in folder A

```
fileX.txt   fileY.txt
hi          red
hello       green
bonjour     orange
```

Suppose in folder B

```
fileX.txt   fileY.txt
hello       red
hi          green
bonjour     blue
```

The output should be that there is no difference for fileX, but there is a difference for fileY.

Comment: What does it mean _to combine the commands_? What is the expected output?

Comment: `how can I combine these to commands?` For every file, execute diff with sort.

Comment: I would simply cd into folderA/folderX and loop over all files, then apply the diff for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you're after:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd folderA || exit
for f in folderX/*.txt; do
    if ! cmp -s <(sort "$f") <(sort "../folderB/$f"); then
        echo "folderA/$f and folderB/$f differ"
    fi
done
```

Note that the script will write no output if the files are the same (when they are sorted).